# Does creating a record type worsen DML performance on the object?

Tags: record-type, dml, performance

If you have an object with no records types versus one with a couple, is performance affected in terms of DML insertion?

I experienced a change in DML performance after creating multiple record types on an object that previously had none which led me to wonder if record types do add a type of complexity that I didn't put much thought into before.

Comment: Do you have any other automation on that object?

Comment: I do - workflows, validation rules, and a process builder. My next step was to create a scratch org and test with none of those to get some idea of CPU time with and without record types

Comment: Do you have any managed packages like DLRS doing automation on your behalf? Generally speaking, it sounds like automation in that org could use some optimization. :-)

Comment: @MarkPond - 100% agree in terms of needing optimization. I'm not necessarily looking at solving that with this question. I was more intrigued at whether there's an discernible impact to performance with having record types vs. having none on a given object.

Comment: The question of how Record Types interact with the automation in your org is not really answerable here.

Comment: In the end, I was asking if the presence of Record types impacts performance (clean slate org). I was using what I experienced in my org as to why I suddenly had the urge to ask the question, but solving that specific test in this forum is not my intent. I can make it clear and remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, no, record types do not add any significant processing time by themselves. They are not generally subject to record locks like many types of parent objects, nor do they do anything much beyond restricting available picklist values. I will not say that the performance difference is definitely exactly zero, but it's close enough that the variations in network latency and server load would make it nearly impossible to discern any measurable difference.

Comment: Picklists and layouts.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Not as far as DML operations are concerned, though.

Comment: That seems reasonable to assume. I was thinking setting the correct default record type by profile (assuming the DML does not provide the record type) might add a bit more complexity but I presume it's still doing that without Record types (assigning the "master" record type).